# How to center a div with a relative width?

Tags: css, html, width, margin

I have a `<div>` which is styled as following:

```
.content{
    width: 70%;
}
```

To center a div, there is the possibility to set the margin to auto (`margin: 0 auto;`) but this only works if I have a fixed size(e.g. 400px). So how can I center my div with relative width?

Comment: It should work.. did you even try adding "margin: 0 auto;" along with width in %??

Comment: text-align: center only centers the text in the div, but not the div itsel

Comment: No need to use text-align-center... "margin: 0 auto;" itself should work..

Comment: Check to see if there are any CSS rules overriding the margins or width settings, check also for floats.

Comment: and if its not working add your code or create a Fiddle of your code..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`margin: 0 auto` will also work for percentage divs.  The side margins will be calculated based off the percentage of the width.

http://jsfiddle.net/B32mh/

Comment: Hum, that´s annoying, It still does not work, I also checked my html code of missing tags or something like that, but everything is fine

Comment: Sorry, my div´s alright, my background and hr s are misplaced

Answer (score 1):

`margin: 0 auto` works as well
or you can use `display: inline-block` on content div and wrap it by div with `text-align: center`

```
<div id="one">one</div>
<br /><br />
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="two">two</div>
</div>
```

Css

```
#one {
    width: 70%;
    height: 100px;
    background: #ccc;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}

#wrap { text-align: center; }
#two {
    width: 70%;
    height: 100px;
    background: #ccc;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;

}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4KhJL/3/

Answer (score 0):

using

```
<body>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="centered"><h1>Hello</h1></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

and CSS

```
.content {
  width: 70%;
  background-color: #e5e5e5;
}

.centered {
  width: 150px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

you get this:

[image]

Demo on JsBin: http://jsbin.com/iDAZeSi/1/

---

edited from answer

just add `margin: 0 auto;` to `.content` so it looks like

```
.content {
  width: 70%;
  background-color: #e5e5e5;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

and you will get:

[image]

Demo on JsBin: http://jsbin.com/iDAZeSi/2/

Comment: I want to center the outer div, and not its content

Comment: then it's exactly the same, as relative width or not, it's still a valid width and for such `margin: 0 auto;` works!